# Design and Solution Question - Spring Boot with Kafka Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, architecture

I am a newbie to Springboot and micro service development and have a question related to Springbot Service designing.

**Requirement -**
We have a requirement where a Springboot Service need to listen to 3 or 4 different Kafka topic individually and create 3 or 4 csv files respectively (After filtering few of the attributes from event message and upload files to FTP server at different time of day).

**Requirement Summary**
[image]

**Design and Inputs Needed**
I am thinking of solution like below -
[image]
#1 I am thinking of having a Kafka Consumer, which can read from one Kafka topics and apply filters and keep on creating files whole day. Once file reaches to100 MB, it will get rotated like A1.csv, A2.csv etc

#2 Also to have job manager which can create cron jobs, which can stitch files once in a day and upload to FTP.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

#3 Would like jobs to be created on the basis of configuration as tomorrow if we want to add new jobs, it can be quick.

#4 How to design this so as scalability can be achieved. As event coming would be huge in numbers.

#5 Will it be recommended to use elastic cache instead of creating multiple files and then sticking them together to a single file.

#6 I also want to have a fail safe logic so as if service fails, I should be able to continue from where I am left off.

Please point me to any existing solution etc which I can refer to. Any API which can help with job/batch scheduler and also to manage configurations.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Thinking of replacing second box, which will read topic and create files to a elastic cache and then file generator to read and create file from cache

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have checkpointing in Kafka, so if application fails, you can start consuming events from the same point. Checkpoint only shifts once your job is done.
2. At this scale, it is good to have spark jobs etc to speed up the computation.
3. You can have distributed cache cluster like Redis or Aerospike to cache some of the files for fast reads.
4. Its good to have job trigger time as configurable which can be changed tomorrow.

Let me know what else would you need to know.

Comment: Please suggest if any Springboot API's available which can be used to create/manage jobs by reading configuration files.

Comment: You can take a look at: https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/ https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/integrating-spark-spring-boot-neeraj-malhotra